# Neo4jTemplate error when using standalone mode

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

In my project I'm using Spring 3 with Neo4j 2.0.1, I was using the embedded mode and everything was working fine.
In my code I use the Neo4jTemplate (@Autowired in my services) as well as the GraphRepository and                               RelationshipOperationsRepository.

I wanted to migrate my coode to use the standalone mode. Here's what I did :

- In spring-context.xml, I made it like this :

```html
<!-- Neo4J -->
 <!-- neo4j:config storeDirectory="${neo.storeDir}" base-package="net.nextep.nextenergy.domain.graph" /-->
 <bean id="graphDatabase" class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase">
     <constructor-arg value="http://localhost:7474/db/data/" index="0"/>
 </bean>
 <neo4j:repositories base-package="net.nextep.nextenergy.repository.graph" />
```

I tried to run it, I got this error :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'neo4jTemplate' is defined
```

I tried then to remove the `@Autowired Neo4jTemplate` from my services, use `@Autowired private SpringRestGraphDatabase graphDB` and create a new Template this way `private Neo4jTemplate template = new Neo4jTemplate((GraphDatabase) graphDB)`

And I still get the same error :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userNodeRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'neo4jTemplate' while setting bean property 'neo4jTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'neo4jTemplate' is defined
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'neo4jTemplate' is defined
...
```

The **UserNodeRepository** :

```
    @Repository
    public interface UserNodeRepository extends GraphRepository<UserNode>, 
                                RelationshipOperationsRepository<UserNode>{
    public UserNode findById(String id);
    public Node findNodeById(String id);
    @Query("match (u:UserNode)-[:HABILITATED]->(f:Folder) where ID(u) = {0} return f")
    public Set<Folder> getAllowedFoldersFirstLevel(UserNode user);

}
```

Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name your bean "graphDatabaseService" and pass it to the config which you didn't create:

```
<neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService" base-package="net.nextep.nextenergy.domain.graph" />

<bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase">
        <constructor-arg value="http://localhost:7474/db/data/" index="0"/>
    </bean>

<neo4j:repositories base-package="net.nextep.nextenergy.repository.graph" />
```

Comment: The solution in pure Java annotations would help me.